How to find a hash in array of hashes by certain value and if not found then by another value
Is there a nice Rails way to implement the following:
I have an array of hashes:
my_obj = [
 {
   gid: 'gid1',
   name: 'name1',
   age: 'age1'
 },
 {
   gid: 'gid2',
   name: 'name2',
   age: 'age2'
 },
 ...

]

I need to find an object that fits the condition
my_obj.detect { _1['name'] == 'name1' }

and if it's empty then I can check the other condition
my_obj.detect { _1['name'] == 'name2' }

but if the first object is found I don't need to look for another concurrence. And it's crucial to look for the first one initially so I can't use ['name1', 'name2'].include? (my_obj['name'])
I've thought of this as
found_obj = my_obj.detect { _1['name'] == 'name1' }
found_obj ||= my_obj.detect { _1['name'] == 'name2' }
found_obj

but probably there is a smarter way to do this?
Thanks

In Rails, you'd typically store your data in a database and use a query to fetch the records.

in this case it's a response I need to parse to store it in the DB :) just some internal logic behind what gets stored

Firstly, the keys in those hashes are symbols, not strings. Therefore, you have to use a slightly different syntax to find a matching hash.
found_object = my_obj.detect { _1[:name] == 'name1' }

When you want to find the first hash that has a name that is included in a list, then you can use:
found_object = my_object.detect { ['name1', 'name2'].include?(_1[:name]) }

This only works when you are sure that the hashes are sorted by name in the array. Or if you do not care if you get name1 or name2 returned.
When the hashes are unsorted, and you absolutely want to make sure that name2 is only returned when name1 does not exist, then you can check one value after the other, like this:
found_object = my_obj.detect { _1[:name] == 'name1' } ||
               my_obj.detect { _1[:name] == 'name2' }


An alternative to the final example would be ['name1', 'name2'].lazy.filter_map {|name| my_obj.detect { _1[:name] == name } }.first

If you really wanna do this in a single loop here is how you can do it.
first_object = nil
second_object = nil

my_obj.each do |obj|
    if obj[:name] == 'name1'
        first_object = obj
        break
    elsif second_object.nil? && obj[:name] == 'name2'
        second_object = obj
    end
end

found_object = first_object.nil? ? second_object : first_object

Or a Slightly refactored version
found_object = find_object(my_obj, 'name1', 'name2')

def find_object(my_obj, name1, name2)
    second_object = nil

    my_obj.each do |obj|
        if obj[:name] == name1
            return obj
        elsif second_object.nil? && obj[:name] == name2
            second_object = obj
        end
    end 
    
    second_object
end


If name1 does not exist then the whole array will be traversed otherwise the function returns as soon as the first object i.e. name1 is found.
If the Array is not large enough then I suggest you to keep using your approach as it provides better readability. It seems rather inexpensive in-memory operation.


This second_object.nil? && obj[:name] == name2 can be changed to second_object&.[](:name) == name2

Another option would be to use Enumerable#group_by to create groups by name and then look them up by the key value
my_obj.group_by {|h| h[:name]}.then {|groups| (groups['name1'] || groups['name2'])&.first }

Using your example this will look like
groups = my_obj.group_by {|h| h[:name] }
#=> {"name1"=>[{:gid=>"gid1", :name=>"name1", :age=>"age1"}], "name2"=>[{:gid=>"gid2", :name=>"name2", :age=>"age2"}]}
groups['name1']
#=> [{:gid=>"gid1", :name=>"name1", :age=>"age1"}]
groups['name1].first 
#=> {:gid=>"gid1", :name=>"name1", :age=>"age1"}

